# Dropping a SQL table by passing a parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, parameters

Trying to create a function that will drop a table in a sql server using a parameter for the table name.

Most of what I have tried is playing with the text and spacing of the query and passing the value directly in. Passing the value directly in functions perfectly fine, however I cannot get the parameter to work properly.

```vb
Private Sub DeleteTable(tablename As String)
    'Add sql params and run command
    SQL.AddParam("@thistablesname", tablename.ToString)

    SQL.ExecQuery("DROP TABLE @thistablesname;", True)
    'SQL.ExecQuery("DROP TABLE Iamanewtable;", True) 'works

    'Report and abort on errors
    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox("Table may have been deleted successfully")

End Sub
```

Comment: You can’t parameterize DDL in SQL Server. You’ll have to build a dynamic SQL command.

Comment: And to make that dynamic sql in the safest way, use a sproc and validate the parameter is a table before concatenation and execution. Interested, why do you need to do this?

Comment: David, thank you for putting my on to the different categories of sql commands. That answers quite a few of my questions and solved a different problem I had been playing with. 
Sean: Thanks for the tip. Its my first time playing with sql coming from visual basic. I haven't figured out how to create tables other than creating a subroutine for it and creating a subroutine to start cleaning up the mess seemed like the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your data is clean, you should be able to just build the string with the name directly and execute it without parameterizing, but beware SQL-Injection.

On a slightly safer approach, you could do with two sql queries.  First, query the database to see if the actual table name DOES exist

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
   WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @parmTable
```

add the table name as the parameter and execute the query.  If the query result returns a row count of 1, then you know you have a good value.  Then you can build your string directly as

```
SQL.ExecQuery( "DROP TABLE " + tablename.ToString, True )
```

Because you pre-qualified the entire table name attempted IS a valid table name via the qualified first query, you can delete with less concern of a sql-injection.

You might even be good to create your own function that you pass a parameter of the table name that does both the check and dynamic SQL to drop the table to if this is going to be a common process.

Comment: Much obliged. Thing is I am damned confused why other querys accept the parameter and not this particular query. As for injection, while this program is just me playing around, I am doing my best to keep that in mind.

Comment: @RjBeagles, the DDL (Data Definition Language) is to build the basis OF tables and columns.  Queries are applies to KNOWN tables and columns, so parameters are just values testing for equality against known columns.  I'm sure there is more to it than that, but simplified.

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE @thistablesname;", cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@thistablesname", tablename));
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```